# Is a downhill scooter lighter than a downhill MTB with same performance?

Tags: weight, downhill, kick-scooter

I saw scooters for rent at some downhill MTB sites. I have never tried them, but I wonder anyway: is a scooter significantly lighter than a bicycle? I assume both are built for downhill riding, including some modest drop-offs.

It should be lighter, because it lacks drivetrain. But maybe not — because bicycles have more mature technology.

Comment: Weight similarities are not about product maturity. A downhill MTB typically used two triangles for strength, bicycle frame built with a single tube have similar engineering challenges to a scooter have been around forever.  They are a relatively heavy design.

Comment: The title asks to compare scooters with DH MTBs with the 'same performance'. I doubt that we can find a scooter that matches the downhill performance of a DH bike (~200mm travel front and rear). Even the ones mentioned by David D's answer only have tiny 26"/19" wheels.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a wide variety of things that go by the name "scooter." Taking a wild guess that you are looking at [something like this](https://www.gravity-scooters.com/en/downhill-/24-gravity-dh-raptor), it's in the same weight range as a downhill mountain bike.

[image: Gravity Downhill "Raptor" scooter]

### Specifications

| Stat | Value |
| --- | --- |
| **Weight** | **16,7 KG** |
| Frame | Chrome-moly steel |
| Fork | RockSh.BoXXer Select.RC2 DA 200mm. Aluminum DH axle 20mm. Weight 2,63 Kg |
| Brakes | Shimano Hydraulic disc brake 4 pistons Ø 203mm |
| Wheels | Front: Ø 26" x 2.35” Tire Schwalbe Space. Rear: Ø 19" x 2.5" Bike Trial |
| Handlebar | 740mm DH |
| Board | Antislide surface. Beech board from Brittany in hot forming. Aluminum scuff guard. Wide board, measures: 700 X 200 X 10 mm. |
| Frame protection | Aluminum 2mm |
| Mudguards | Aluminum 2mm |

Comment: Is this thing serious or some kind of expensive novelty item?

Comment: This being made of steel suggests it's not a fully optimised design (I like steel bikes, but they do come in a little heavier than aluminium).  It should be possible to build one lighter than a bike with a drivetrain.

Comment: @ojs I discovered last week during a ride that there are even electric version of them... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mlvXCExXcGU (the video is 6y old, so it looks like it didn't take off).

Answer (score 3):

You must bear in mind that unlike the bicycle frame that triangulates, the scooter is a linear frame and therefore its structure needs extra reinforcement for extreme downhill. The solution is to build a frame in chrome-molybdenum steel, the most resistant, in order to guarantee maximum durability when making big jumps. This combined with a sandwich the wood to give flexibility and strength to the set.

Watch this video to understand what I mean.

---

A downhill bike can weigh 7kg to 15kg. A downhill scooter usually weighs about 16-17kg